# Synaptics 3 finger swipe doesn't work for navigating in Browsers anymore

Tags: windows, windows-10, synaptics-touchpad

I used the 3 finger swipe gesture to navigate forth and back when browsing. Since several days this gesture is now assigned as Application change. I looked in the synaptics settings (see screenshot) and there is only the option to deactivate the 3 finger gesture (then the 3 finger gesture is completely disabled) or just let it be assigned as application change.

It's very annoying that the navigating gesture does not work anymore, any hints?

[image]

[image]

Here some background Infos:

OS: Win10 64 Bit Build: 14393.351 (Version 1607)

Synaptics driver version: 19.0.17.115

Hardware: X240 Lenovo

Comment: The reason you lost the gesture is because you installed the generic Synaptic driver instead of the Lenovo Synaptic driver.

Comment: I havent installed anything. That happened automatically. Like said it was perfectly working before. But thanks for the tip i will try to install the lenovo driver again. It worries me that it somehow changed to the generic synaptics driver.

Comment: It was working before what exactly? Telling us it used to work doesn't tell us anything really.  What happen in the last few days.  What Windows 10 build are you using?  Is it an Insider Preview build?  Update your question and be specific.

Comment: The 3 finger swipe to navigate back and forth in explorer/chrome etc. does not work. It worked perfectly for a year. Sorry when my question was not good. I updated the build nr of windows 10, no i don't participate in the insiders programm.

Comment: So what changed, with regards to your computer, when the gesture stopped working?

Comment: There was a windows update done on 4th November. It replaced a synaptics pointing device driver probably. https://abload.de/img/test3qqyn.png

Comment: To solve it, I would just uninstall the device and reinstall it using the software directly from Lenovo. If you do this without being connected to the internet (of course download it first) you shouldn't have any Windows interference. If Windows still overrides your install, select "don't install/hide update" in Windows update.

Comment: Did not help :/ I turned off wifi, deinstalled the touchpad driver in system settings, after restart i installed the application offered on lenovo website suited for win10 32/64 bit. In the ultranav settings, i still have only one setting in the gestures tab. (no difference to the screenshot posted above)

Comment: Did you uninstall the Lenovo application and the driver?  You can also delete the driver itself with Device Manager.  Do this after you block the driver update.